# Exporting c++ function, declared in vb6, getting "remote procedure call failed" runtime error

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2003, managed-c++

I have a dll written in C++ that is being exported like so:

```
extern "C" {
    extern _declspec(dllexport) (VOID) Merge(LPCSTR szFileName, LPCSTR szMergeString, DWORD dwAlignment, BOOL fRepeat);
}
```

That function is defined elsewhere as:

```
extern _declspec(dllexport) (VOID) Merge(LPCSTR szFileName, LPCSTR szMergeString, DWORD dwAlignment, BOOL fRepeat)
{   
    Tools::Merge(gcnew String(szFileName), gcnew String(szMergeString), dwAlignment, fRepeat == TRUE);
}
```

In my vb6 dll, I have declared the remote call like this:

```
Private Declare Sub Merge Lib "Tools.dll" (fileName As String, mergeString As String, Alignment As Long, repeated As Boolean)
```

Then I call it in the code like this:

```
Merge strPageFileName, "COPY", 5, True
```

When I run the app, I get "Automation error: the remote procedure call failed" in a message box.

`Tools.dll` is in C:\Windows\system32.  I tested with a bad dll name, to make sure that wasn't the problem, and get an error saying it could not find the file, so I know that's not it.  Anything else I need to do to get this to work?

**EDIT:** Changing the variable type per xxbbcc's answer below allowed this to function correctly.  However, it created a new, so far utterly unsolvable problem.  I created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571237/what-is-the-vberror-returned-by-vartype-in-vb6) that has some of the details about it.

The remote call is happening in a COM+ dll, inside a function that returns type `integer` to another non-COM dll. For some strange reason, the COM+ dll's function is now returning a variant of type `VT_ERROR` instead of an integer.  I have tested this thoroughly and determined that it does not matter what I do with the return value beforehand, setting it to any value, etc, it always returns an error.  The odd part is that the value of the error is apparently 0.  I have called `CInt(returnValue)`, `CStr(returnValue)`, and `CLng(returnValue)`, and they return `0`, `Error 0`, and `0`, respectively.

I have been unable to find any information explaining why a function that is supposed to return an integer would suddenly be returning an error instead.  This is giving me a type mismatch error in the non-COM+ function, as it tries to assign the return to a local integer.  Changing that to a variant allowed me to do the casts above.  Calling `VarType(returnValue)` gives 10, which is `vbError`. We don't want to potentially lose failure information from other calls inside the COM+ dll, so I can't just ignore the return value.

Comment: Have you tried running `dumpbin /exports` to verify that your exported function is named exactly how your VB6 client is looking for it? (That is, is the function name completely unmangled in the DLL?)

Another thing to check: is your C++ function actually called? If you put a breakpoint in it, is it hit?

Comment: Yes, it is showing the function `Merge` just as you'd expect.  The problem with debugging is that this is located on a server, and there's no convenient way to debug on it or test on my PC.  I've tried doing this the other way around, with regasm and running this as a COM dll, and that way gives error 438, indicating that it can't find the function.

Comment: Just to verify: did you use `regasm` or `regsvr32`? If this is a plain C/C++ DLL, regasm won't do anything. Plus you can't export plain functions to COM without a type library - do you have one for your DLL? (You can export global functions to VB6 that way but the type library is required then.)

Comment: Yes, I played around with this quite a bit.  When I ran regasm I had it create the type library.  In that case, it seemed to create correct registry entries for an enum class that just had a set of values for the alignment, but it didn't create an entry for the other class with the merge function.  I am able to see the alignment values exposed in vb6, but not the function.  It fails to build when I dim the class as an object and then set it to a tools class.

Comment: In VB6, you cannot see static functions of .NET classes - I don't believe the type library creator creates a module entry for that. You can try looking for `Tools.Merge` in VB6 but I doubt it's there (never tried this). For your global `Merge` function, use a DEF file to export it and then VB6 should be able to call it. You still need to fix your `Declare` statement as per my answer. Right now you're trying to call your function with the wrong parameters.

Comment: No, you're right, it's not there.

Comment: We need more details on the COM+ part of the system. How is the COM+ object being called? How is the method on the COM+ object being declared? You should probably post the details in a new question (and link them if you want). This sounds like you are calling a method that succeeds but you are interpreting the output wrong somewhere. Remember how [I said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16572475/2230) that vbError values where scode`s (HRESULTs) and that an scode could indicate error or success? A VbError of 0 is the scode/HRESULT called `S_OK`, the standard COM scode for "completed successfully".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution to this has been to write a tiny c++ console application that calls the exported function, and call the exe from within the vb6 dll.

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` should be defined as `Long` in VB6 and the value passed for it should be `0` or `1`, not boolean values. It should also be `ByVal` - since parameters are passed by values in C / C++, you must make sure that your VB6 program follows that. Right now your VB6 program passes a pointer to a `Boolean`, rather than an actual `Long`. Your strings should also be defined as `ByVal`.

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187912) - while dated - has some useful information about why strings should be passed from VB6 as `ByVal` to C code.

Another thing - I never successfully exported a function to VB6 using declspec(dllexport). I did a lot of C / VB6 coding in the past but the only way it ever worked was through DEF files. I can't explain why (it may have been because of my ignorance). Ignore this part of my answer if fixing the BOOL parameter solves your issue. :)

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem, as the file is now merged correctly, but I'm getting a type mismatch error just after this code now, which causes the app to fail and not complete, so I'm trying to work it out.  Once that gets untangled, I'll accept this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeMajsterski thank you, let me know if you have more questions. Glad to hear your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the String parameters in your VB6 Declare statement ByVal.  Change "filename as String" to "ByVal filename as String", etc.

Comment: No luck.  Thanks for the suggestion though.