# What is the vbError returned by VarType in VB6?

Tags: error-handling, vb6

I have been searching for this all over the web, but everything is either talking about the `ErrObject` class, or the constant `vbError` returned by the `VarType` function.  I want to know what that type actually *is*, e.g. an `integer` is something like `4`, a `string` is something like `"hello world"`, etc.

For a little background, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263402%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is a link to the official MSDN page about `VarType`, which shows all the constants it returns and what they represent.  What is `Error value`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are familiar with COM in C/C++, you should know that from that perspective `VarType()` is a simple function that essentially extracts the value of the `vt` member from the `Variant` passed in as a parameter. The possible values of the `vt` member are documented in many places, such as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908601.aspx).

If you check inside of the COM system headers (e.g. WTypes.h distributed as part of in the Windows SDK), you will see that the `VbError` value of 10 indeed maps to the C/C++ enum value of `VT_ERROR`.

```
enum VARENUM
    {  VT_EMPTY   = 0,
       ...
       VT_ERROR  = 10,
       ...
    } ;
```

The MSDN link above describes the meaning of a `vt` that equals `VT_ERROR` as follows:

> An SCODE was specified. The type of the error is specified in **scode**.
>   Generally, operations on error values should raise an exception or propagate the error to the return value, as appropriate.

So, here's basically what it means:

A `Variant` obviously supports storing many types of values, and among them is the obscure possibility of storing an "Error Code". More correctly, these codes are formally called `scode`'s, because they can indicate many types of "success" as well as "failures". Most people refer to these codes as `HRESULT`s.

These codes are the same kind of "Error Codes" that you get from `Err.Number` in VB6. So, you can tell a `Variant` to distinguish an "Error Code" from just a plain number.

In reality, few programs or COM components - if any - will ever put error codes in Variants. Almost everybody just issues COM Exceptions to communicate errors (this mechanism is exposed in VB6 via the `Err` object). Even those components that return error codes outside of the COM Exception mechanism, would likely do so in typed variables (e.g. `Long`'s).

Therefore, the reason this possible return value exists is for completeness. You will almost never see it in real life.

*(Edit: Remove bit about not being able to create an "Error" variant. @Joe proved me wrong on that. You can use `CVErr()` to create one)*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Although I was unable to resolve the issue that caused me to post this question, this was informative nonetheless.

Comment: @JoeMajsterski, Pleasure to help; it got me to learn something new too. So, what was the actual issue? It wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: It's a very bizarre one.  I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429119/exporting-c-function-declared-in-vb6-getting-remote-procedure-call-failed that I am going to expand with the details.

Comment: One other point, you can't implicitly cast these errors to type long or integer.

Comment: FYI, in VBscript, an array created by the Array() function with an empty position in the arguments list, will create an array with the expected number of elements, but when the empty element is accessed, its type is vbError. So, VarType( Array(1,,2,3)(1))  returns vbError. I have a legacy VB6 app that builds a dynamic vbscript from DB data, using a script file with templating tags. I hoped that rendering an argument list with empty positions to an Array() function would result in a vbNull when those positions were accessed, but unfortunately, this isn't the case.

Answer (score 4):

In VB6 and VBA, error values are created by calling the [CVErr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262707(v=vs.60).aspx) function.

This function returns a Variant whose VarType is vbError, and for which the `IsError` function returns `True`.

A typical use case for this is an Excel UDF that returns a Variant: if you return an error value, it will display as #VALUE!.